# How to setup Hyper-V for home and office

Tags: networking, hyper-v

I have a Hyper-V VM that serves a website that I use for debugging purposes.

At my home I have a 192.168.20.* network range.

At my office I have 172.17.200.*.

I have set the the Linux VM network to a fixed 172.17.200.* address and it works fine at the office.

Is it possible to configure it in such a way that I can use it at both locations without having to constantly change the VM IP address and my Windows hosts file as I have a local domain pointed to the fixed address?

Comment: Is the VM accessed from elsewhere on the LAN or only from the host itself?

Comment: @u1686_grawity, only from the host

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Create a new "Virtual Switch" in Hyper-V and set it to "Internal" mode. This will make a new "vEthernet" network interface show up on the host, which can have its own IP configuration separate from the real LAN.
2. Add a second network interface to the VM and connect it to this vSwitch (in addition to the existing "External" vSwitch that it uses for Internet access).
3. Configure both the host and the VM to use a new IP network that conflicts with neither the home network nor the office network (e.g. 172.31.0.0/24, with .1 as the host and .2 as the VM).

   (Use any suitable netmask, e.g. 255.255.255.0 aka /24, and leave the 'gateway' field empty. If you want to reduce chances of conflicting with VPNs or public Wi-Fi networks, you could configure an IPv6 [ULA](https://unique-local-ipv6.com/) address in addition to – or even instead of – the IPv4 address.)

Comment: Just trying to understand #3... Host is a Windows PC. So I need to disable DHCP and set a static IP on the vEthernet External network connection and on the Linux VM? Or somewhere else.
Thanks for your help.

Comment: No, you need to add a *second* network connection and set a static IP on that.

Comment: I think I have it working - thank you very much!
I set the 172.31.0.1 address on the internal adapter that I added. I wasn't sure about default gateway or DNS so I left them blank but it seems to work.

Comment: Keep them empty; it's a single-subnet network and a gateway is not needed to access hosts that are in the same subnet.